# tax income - working less than 12 months

Tags: income-tax, income-tax-refund

If I work less than a year (6 months) and I earn 26,000 per annum. However, I didn't work before, therefore in March the overall amount will be apox. 13,000. Am I entitled to the tax return as they deduct the tax off my salary monthly?

Comment: Please add a country tag, as how tax withholding is managed varies widely.

Comment: The answer depends on how much is withheld - you may want to add that too (along with the country tag, of course).

Comment: also please specify the start date so we can understand the significance of March.

Comment: Hi new user.  Yes, ***IF*** you paid more tax than you had to, yes you will get it back.  But be careful - the taxman always finds some reason you have to pay more. You know?  But yes in THEORY you would get back any excess.

Comment: _**If**_ you are in the UK (clues: use of "March": tax year runs 6th April to 5th April ~= "end of March"; plus use of "per annum") then yes you should either get (or be able to claim) the money back after the end of the tax year; or -- if you continue working -- they may reduce the next years tax deductions to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

The amount of taxes withheld in a period will be based on your income for the period extrapolated out to an entire year, and taking into account the number of allowances you claimed.  So if you only work 6 months, and have no other income, then your total income for the year will be less than what your wihholdings were based on, and you probably will get a refund.

However, you won't know for sure until you actually file your tax return and calculate the amount due taking into account all deductions, exemptions, credits, and wihholdings. It's possible that you claimed too many exemptions on your W-4 and had less tax withheld than you should have, and would then *owe* tax when you file.